# What does "vector<int> Solution::primesum(int n)" mean?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Being a beginner in C++ I am facing a difficulty to understand this thing:

```cpp
vector<int> Solution::primesum(int n)
```

Code:

```
 vector<int> Solution::primesum(int n){
        vector<bool> isprime(n+1);    
  for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)

         isprime[i]=1;
        isprime[0]=0;
        isprime[1]=0;
        for(int i=2;i*i<=n;i++){
            if(isprime[i]){
                for(int j=i*2;j<=n;j+=i)
                 isprime[j]=0;
            }
        }
        vector<int>ans(2);
        for(int i=2;i<=n/2;i++){
            if(isprime[i] && isprime[n-i]){
                ans[0]=i;
                ans[1]=n-i;
                return ans;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a member function of `Solution` that returns a `vector<int>`. What exactly is it you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, you could. `vector<int> Solution::primesum(int n)` suggests that `primesum` is a method of class `Solution`.

Comment: Thank you....I didnt knew about member functions .

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code there must be a class `Solution` which has a member function `primesum` taking an integer argument and returning a vector of integer type:

```cpp
class Solution
{ 
   public:
   vector<int> primesum(int);
};
```

Only then you can define it outside using scope resolution operator `::`:

```cpp
vector<int> Solution::primesum(int n) 
{ // Definition }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution means a class named "Solution" that represents a custom data type. And the primesum(int n) is a member function in the definition of the class with the return type , While the vector is a data type used as an enhanced version of int[] or char[](or string).

```
class Solution
{
public:
   vector<int> primesum(int) //just like int* primesum(int); amount to returning a array
   ...
};
```

```
Solution::vector<int> Solution::primesum(int n){
   ...
}
```

If possoble, give more details for us to understand and answer your question.